# In AWS. I collated the result onto the master node and then prepared to write to S3 with the following error:

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, amazon-s3, hdfs

In Hadoop, I collated the result onto the master node and then prepared to write to S3 with the following error:

> 18/08/19 20:10:13 WARN DataStreamer: Exception for
>   BP-2033025931-192.168.3.27-1534682170082:blk_1073741835_1011
>   java.io.EOFException: Unexpected EOF while trying to read response
>   from server at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.PBHelperClient.vintPrefixed(PBHelperClient.java:402)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.PipelineAck.readFields(PipelineAck.java:213)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer$ResponseProcessor.run(DataStreamer.java:1073)
>
> 18/08/19 20:10:13 WARN DataStreamer: Error Recovery for
>   BP-2033025931-192.168.3.27-1534682170082:blk_1073741835_1011 in
>   pipeline
>   [DatanodeInfoWithStorage[192.168.3.141:50010,DS-fe8dd87d-2b16-4746-b5ee-c65a836cebb4,DISK],
>   DatanodeInfoWithStorage[192.168.3.183:50010,DS-54ceb3d7-fdc3-4a8e-8df1-ab9c53f25628,DISK],
>   DatanodeInfoWithStorage[192.168.3.106:50010,DS-4640296a-8a2a-4223-9759-f592aca85e77,DISK]]:
>   datanode
>   0(DatanodeInfoWithStorage[192.168.3.141:50010,DS-fe8dd87d-2b16-4746-b5ee-c65a836cebb4,DISK])
>   is bad.

Then a second error occurred：

> com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Your socket connection to the server was not read from or written to within the timeout period. Idle connections will be closed. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: RequestTimeout; Request ID: BF10123C46AC4; S3 Extended Request ID: SXF+/rJOtW8714PGg0GEz9bgJuKuf/2BNOskx0JdTa02g1a/3igd3vfuaO7zI=)

These two requestIDs are not complete, because I don't know what they can do for them.

Answer (score 1):

This time there is no such error when i ran it again.I guess this is an accidental event.Then I added the following code：

```
ClientConfiguration s3ClientConfig = new ClientConfiguration().withMaxErrorRetry(10)
            .withConnectionTimeout(3 * 60 * 1000)
            .withSocketTimeout(3 * 60 * 1000);
```

I hope it will work in the future.

Comment: Today, my job reported the same error again.So, this configuration is not working.I have not found a solution yet.But,I can be sure this is an accident.

Comment: Did you find a configuration that worked?